# Webpack 4 file-loader changes svg file content to __webpack_public_path__

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a project that uses Webpack 4. I use file-loader to handle images in html and fonts in the styles. But for the images, file-loader creates the image in dist folder but puts **"module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "assets/fonts/main-logo.svg";"** string in it. So i can see the correct path in the html but i can't see the image. Here is my webpack file:

### webpack.common.js

```
    const path = require('path');

module.exports = {

  entry: "./src/index.js",
  module: {
    rules: [

      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: ["html-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            esModule: false,
            name: "[name].[ext]",
            outputPath: "assets/images"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)([\?]?.*)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            esModule: false,
            name: "[name].[ext]",
            outputPath: "assets/fonts"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And this is the **webpack.dev.js** file for development env.

```
const common = require('./webpack.common');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "development",
  output:  {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/template.html"
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you try using `outputPath: path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/images")`?

Answer (score 5):

You are testing for files with `.svg` extension in two rules with the same loader.

If your intention is to output SVGs to `assets/fonts` you should remove the extension from the image files test:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {

  entry: "./src/index.js",
  module: {
    rules: [

      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: ["html-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            esModule: false,
            name: "[name].[ext]",
            outputPath: "assets/images"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)([\?]?.*)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            esModule: false,
            name: "[name].[ext]",
            outputPath: "assets/fonts"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to output SVGs to `assets/images`, you should remove the extension from the fonts test:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {

  entry: "./src/index.js",
  module: {
    rules: [

      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: ["html-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            esModule: false,
            name: "[name].[ext]",
            outputPath: "assets/images"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot)([\?]?.*)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            esModule: false,
            name: "[name].[ext]",
            outputPath: "assets/fonts"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```